# Checking if a file exists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, dialog

I am using a simple python script to search and play songs on my laptop. The code goes as follows :-

```
    import os
    d_name = raw_input("enter drive name:-")
    choice = raw_input("song or video(s/v):-")
    if(choice == 's'):
        s_name = raw_input("enter song name:- ")
        flag = 1
    elif(choice=='v'):
        s_name = raw_input("enter video name:-")
        flag = 2
    if(flag == 1):
        f_s_name = "start "+d_name+":/"+s_name+".mp3"
    elif(flag == 2):
        f_s_name = "start "+d_name+":/"+s_name+".mp4"
    dir_list = os.listdir("d_name:/")
    i=0
    while(1):
        if(not(os.system(f_s_name))):
            break
        else:
        if(flag == 1):
            f_s_name = "start "+d_name+":/"+dir_list[i]+"/"+s_name+".mp3"
         elif(flag == 2):
            f_s_name = "start "+d_name+":/"+dir_list[i]+"/"+s_name+".mp4"
     i = i+1
```

the above program works fine but when one of the calls to the function os.system() fails until the required condition matches it pops out a dialog box claiming that the song is not there until it is found. How can i prevent popping up of that dialog box?

Comment: Please please, remove those unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to test whether the file you're about to `start` actually exists; if it is not found, do not try to `start` that file:

```
import os

....

filename = '{}:/{}/{}.mp3'.format(d_name, dir_list[i], s_name)
if os.path.exists(filename):
    system('start ' + filename)
else:
    print "File {} was not found".format(filename)
```